# How to read a text file and store values in arrays

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

I am having a problem setting up parallel arrays. How do I read a text file and print it on the compiler output window? The stuff.txt contains the following data:

```
Sue 57
Chad 52
Ram 43
```

Hopefully someone can help. Here is my code so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class nameAge
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
   {
     String name[] = new String[3]; 
     int ages[] = new int[3]; 

     Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("stuff.txt")); 
     int i = 0; 
     while (inFile.hasNextLine()) 
     { 
        name[i] = inFile.next(); 
        ages[i] = inFile.nextInt(); 
     }

     System.out.println(name[i] + " " + ages[i] ); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend first that you change from Arrays to ArrayList, because you *shouldn't* make the assumption of the size of the file.

I would change it to this:

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> ages = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Then, your while loop can do this:

```
while(lineScanner.hasNext()){
   names.add(lineScanner.next());
   ages.add(lineScanner.nextInt());
}
```

Then, you can just set up a for loop through those ArrayLists which (theoretically) should be the same length but maybe you can do some error checking, like this:

```
if(names.size() != ages.size()){
   System.out.println("Something wen't wrong - the number of names and ages are not equal.");
} else{
   for(int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++){
      System.out.println(names.get(i) + " " + ages.get(i));
   }
}
```

Some stuff might need to be tweaked, as I don't have my IDE open, but hopefully a push in the right spot.

Comment: Also, looking over your code, I can see an issue in your logic. You use a while loop to go over the file, but are not changing i in your while loop, so you're just repeatedly setting the values at index 0. Changing to the above should counter that, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
while (inFile.hasNextLine()) { 
    String line = inFile.nextLine();
    Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
    while(lineScanner.hasNext()) {
        name[i] = lineScanner.next();
        ages[i] = lineScanner.nextInt();
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It compiles but gives me no such element expection.

Comment: Now it gives me ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. I tried to change to size of array, but it gives me out which looks like.... null 0

Comment: @sammy it is probably because you have more than 3 lines

Comment: @sammy It is maybe helpful to update your current code (and mention that you've changed it with the help of `Jean Logeart`) and please show us the content of the `stuff.txt`. Don't forget to anonymize the content if it requires data privacy.

Comment: Yes, it is ``lineScanner.next()``, bad c/p